# Which do you like - Visual SVN or Ankhsvn?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

Putting aside the fact that one is open-source, which tool is more feature rich and performant for SVN support within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently switched back to Ankhsvn (2.0) from VisualSVN. Prior to VisualSVN I was using Ankhsvn (1.0).

I prefer AnkhSVN 2.0 because it integrates with Visual Studio as a source control module, rather than an add-in and as a result it feels more like using Visual SourceSafe (which I am forced to use at my 9 to 5). Basically it integrates with Visual Studio the way Microsoft intended source control to integrate with Visual Studio.

For me it simplifies going back and forth between Visual SourceSafe and Subversion since they both behave essentially the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I like AnkhSVN mostly because it is free.  BUT, I love the VisualSVN server.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like either one.  Using the shell/tortoise was preferable for me.

Answer (score 1):

I paid for VisualSVN, its just worth it, even though I usually side with free (and even inferior) software. And by separating concerns by handing the actual SVN stuff to TortoisSVN, you get the best of both worlds.

Ultimately its down to how you work, and what you're used to, and since I was already using to TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN was a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way that VisualSVN keeps you closer to tortoise. I also like its diff tools better.

I'm not sure if they changed it, but Ankh did not allow renaming of files in VS when I last used it. That was a pretty big pain for me as I have refactoritis and generally suck at naming files really well the first time.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN for me. I've found it to be much more stable than Ankh.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to VisualSVN because: a) it delegates most of the work to TortoseSVN, and b) it handles all move/rename shenanigans I throw at it from the Solution Explorer.